# downloading a file using http.post in angular is returning Unknown.html or download.html

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am new to angular. I am trying to hook the Ui app written in angular with a Java Spring-boot application acting as API. The endpoint where I am stuck is a http post where I am trying to download a file. Below is the code of the Angular and java app. Now I am able to download the file I want to successfully, but somehow I am getting two files. First file is a UnKnown.html file ( the one that gets downloaded straight away on making the http call) and second is the actual file I intended. How do I get rid of this Unknown.html file? I have spent hours on this but no luck ! Code as below

Angular Code

```
  downloadDocument(doc: JDocument) {
    var body = { id: doc.projectId + "/" + doc.documentName };
    this._http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/documents/downloadDocument`, body,{responseType: 'blob',withCredentials: true,headers: new HttpHeaders().append("Content-Type", "application/json")})
    .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        FileSaver.saveAs(response, doc.documentName);
      },
      errorResponse => {
        console.log("post call Response", errorResponse);
      }
    );
  }
```

Java Code on server

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/downloadDocument")
        public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadFile(@RequestBody IdType docId) {
            //id here refers to the filename
            ByteArrayOutputStream downloadInputStream = documentsService.downloadFile(docId.getId());

            org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource ts = new ByteArrayResource(downloadInputStream.toByteArray());
           
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .contentType(contentType(docId.getId()))
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + docId.getId() + "\"")
                    .body(ts);
        }

        private MediaType contentType(String filename) {
            String[] fileArrSplit = filename.split("\\.");
            String fileExtension = fileArrSplit[fileArrSplit.length - 1];
            switch (fileExtension) {
                case "txt":
                    return MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN;
                case "png":
                    return MediaType.IMAGE_PNG;
                case "jpg":
                    return MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG;
                default:
                    return MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using post to get data *from* a server?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be a "get" request?